# Rails routing error, with a basic controller and form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a helpdesk controller which controls models such as the Guides model. I am trying to create a create page for it at helpdesk/new however I seem to be having some routing errors. I'm sure it is a simple mistake so any help would be appreciated:)

helpdesk/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @guide do |guide| %>
    <%= guide.text_field :title %>
    <%= guide.text_area :content %>
    <%= guide.text_field :youtube %>
    <%= guide.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Routes

```
  resources :helpdesk
```

Helpdesk controller

```
  def new
    @guide = Guide.new
  end

  def create
    @guide = Guide.create(guide_params)
    if @guide.save
          format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
          format.json {  }
    else
          format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
          format.json {  }
    end
  end
```

Guide model

```
class Guide < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Error:

```
undefined method `guides_path' for #<#<Class:0x7512d98>:0x72f3a80>
```

On line:

```
<%= form_for @guide do |guide| %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The line `resources :helpdesk` will create the following routes for you:

```
GET /helpdesks
GET /helpdesk/new
POST /helpdesks
GET /helpdesk/:id
GET /helpdesk/:id/edit
PATCH /helpdesk/:id
DELETE /helpdesk/:id
```

By using the `form_for` helper with an instantiated new object called `@guide`, Rails magic expects you to have a guides resource, rather than a helpdesk resource.

You can amend form_for to include the url you want the form to post to so amend to read:

```
<%= form_for @guide, url: helpdesks_path do |f| %>
```

This will POST the form to the relevant created route. You will need to do similar for the edit action.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a `GuidesController` to control the `Guide` model.  But if you're set on it then you can set the url to use.  Rails looks for `guides_path` because it's a `Guide` model

```
<%= form_for @guide, url: helpdesk_path do |guide| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add:

```
resources :guides
```

To your `config/routes.rb` file and you should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

You should have a `GuidesController` as @japed said, but for this situation try this in your `config/routes.rb`:

```
resources :guides, controller: :helpdesk
```